# C# What type in an assembly does not belong to a Namespace?

Tags: c#, types, reflection, namespaces

```
Console.WriteLine("Please choose a method to obtain a table:\n");

Type[] current = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
                    
for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < current.Length; i++)
{
   if (current[i].IsClass && current[i].Namespace.Contains("parser", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                current[i].Name.Contains("parser", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", j, current[i].Name);
     j++;
  }
}
```

In this code the condition

> current[i].Namespace

is highlighted as

> Dereference of a possibly null reference.

I've checked Type metadata and found that the property returns null if the current instance has no namespace.

My question is what kind of type in an assembly could not belong to a Namespace?

Comment: I'd have to test to be sure but I'm guessing that you can set the root namespace for a project to be blank, which would presumably equate to no namespace. As for that code, if you aren't already aware, you can use `current[i].Namespace?.Contains("parser", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true` to avoid the warning.

Comment: I just checked a project with a custom `Label` class and I commented out the `namespace` line in that class file and it compiled fine, showing the type with no qualifying namespace where it was used in a form designer code file. I didn't even have to change the root namespace for the project. If you don't put a class declaration inside a namespace then that class has no namespace. Who knew?

Comment: @John thank you, I can also use the null-forgiving operator, e.g. Namespace!.Contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18877258/john), it is possible to set the root namespace for a project to be blank, which would presumably equate to no namespace.